# Table centering and margin issues

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating a template for an email based in a table format for consistency. I am having trouble with two styling elements.

1. `.productWrap` - I cannot get the `border-bottom` to show up and the margin does not add on.
2. I cannot get the image of the sun to align in the center of the container. I have tried adding `text-align: center;margin:0 auto 30px 0;display:block;` to the `<tr>` and the image itself. Neither work.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with these two things?

```css
img {
    border: none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    max-width: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    width: 100%;
}
table td {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
/* -------------------------------------

            BODY & CONTAINER

        ------------------------------------- */
.red {
 color: #b82222;
 font-weight: bold;
}
p {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 color: #4d4d4d;
}
.bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.signature {
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-style: italic;
}
.container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 580px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 580px;
}
.content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 580px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}
.footer {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
 max-width: 580px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}
.footer td, .footer p, .footer span, .footer a {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* ------- Product Section ------- */
.productWrap {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 padding: 10px 0;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;
 z-index: 1;
}
.productImgCont {
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
}
.productImg {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.productContent {
 width: 250px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.productName {
 color: #4d4d4d;
 font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.productName:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background: #1b8c00;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.productLink {
 color: #1b8c00;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: .9rem;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <table class="main">
                    <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr style="width: 100%;text-align:center;display:block;margin:0 auto 30px auto;">
                                    <td>
                                    <p>
           <a href="">
            <img src="https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/system/downloadable_items/519_solsticeflare.jpg">
           </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
          <p>Hi John,</p>
                                        <p>Here's your daily mower update</p>
                                    </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="productWrap">
         <td class="productImgCont">
          <img src="https://www.getmowers.com/wp-content/uploads/w2464-1.jpeg" class="productImg" alt="$product_name">
                                    </td>
         <td class="productContent">
          <p class="productName">60IN JOHN DEERE 1026R SUB-COMPACT UTILITY 4X4 TRACTOR W/ 25HP YANMAR!!</p>
          <p class="productCost">$10,500.00</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
           </div>     
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added "display: block” to the .productWrap. And for the image I removed some styling attributes and it works just fine.

```css
img {
    border: none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    max-width: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    width: 100%;
}

table td {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}


/* -------------------------------------

            BODY & CONTAINER

        ------------------------------------- */

.red {
    color: #b82222;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: #4d4d4d;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.signature {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 580px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 580px;
}

.content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 580px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.main {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}

.footer {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.footer td,
.footer p,
.footer span,
.footer a {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}


/* ------- Product Section ------- */

.productWrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

.productImgCont {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}

.productImg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.productContent {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.productName {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.productName:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #1b8c00;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.productLink {
    color: #1b8c00;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: .9rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <table class="main">
                    <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr style="width: 100%;margin:0 auto 30px auto;">
                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="">
                                            <img src="https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/system/downloadable_items/519_solsticeflare.jpg" width="128">
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <p>Hi John,</p>
                                        <p>Here's your daily mower update</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="productWrap">
                                    <td class="productImgCont">
                                        <img src="https://www.getmowers.com/wp-content/uploads/w2464-1.jpeg" class="productImg" alt="$product_name">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="productContent">
                                        <p class="productName">60IN JOHN DEERE 1026R SUB-COMPACT UTILITY 4X4 TRACTOR W/ 25HP YANMAR!!</p>
                                        <p class="productCost">$10,500.00</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.